# Nginx 1.8.1 and Ruby on Rails session conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

How could I approach troubleshooting an Nginx 1.8.1 502 Bad Gateway response with Ruby on Rails 4.0?

Here's what I know:

- The browser shows me an Nginx 1.8.1 502 Bad Gateway when I POST a user login form.
- When I open a Chrome Incognito or Firefox Private browsing session, then I can POST the user login form with the expected response.
- When I see the 502 Bad Gateway, I can simultaneously watch the Rails app's logs and I can see that the POST request was received, processed by the appropriate route, controller, and action, followed by a 200 OK response.
- The request is near instantaneous. I can see it logged via Rails (Puma), and the browser, so I do not think this is an Nginx timeout problem.

What further information would be useful to gather?  Is there already a probable root cause indicated with what I know?

Comment: What about the Nginx access/error logs? Do they hold any clues?

Comment: I don't know what the Nginx logs report. The system admin has access, and I don't.